# Jquery Bootgrid loads data initially then blanks out

Tags: jquery, datagrid

I can't figure out what I've got wrong here.  I have a jquery bootgrid and I'm doing it exactly as the example directs, but what happens is that the page initially loads with data, unformatted, then the jquery bootgrid formatting gets applied for a brief second followed by a blank out and just the message "Loading..." in place of the data.  So it's working initially but then fails and I don't know why.  Going through the debugger I get an exception about url can't be blank, but I'm not using an API to get this data, I'm reading it in and loading it into the table directly (as seen in the code).  If I include a nonsense url setting I get "no results" which makes sense because there's no data coming from that url, but the grid operates properly.  How can I get this to work without the url parameter?

Html:

```
 <table id="ResultsGrid" name="ResultsGrid" runat="server" data-side-pagination="server" data-pagination="true" class="table table-extracondensed table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr class="info">
                    <th data-column-id="CaseID" data-identifier="true" data-formatter="link">Case ID</th>
                    <th data-column-id="Status">Status</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @if (Model.Results != null && Model.Results.Count() > 0)
                {

                    foreach (var result in Model.Results)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td><a style="cursor:pointer" href="/ViewCase?id=@result.CaseID">@result.CaseID</a></td>
                            <td>@result.Status</td>

                        </tr>
                    }
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Javascript:

```
       $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.datepicker').datepicker();

            $("#ResultsGrid").bootgrid({
                ajax: true,
                post: function () {
                    return {
                        id: "b0df282a-0d67-40e5-8558-c9e93b7befed"
                    };
                },
                selection: true,
                multiSelect: true,
                formatters: {
                    "link": function (column, row) {
                        return "<a href=\"#\">" + column.id + ": " + row.id + "</a>";
                    }
                }

            }).on("selected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, rows) {
                var rowIds = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    rowIds.push(rows[i].id);
                }
                alert("Select: " + rowIds.join(","));
            }).on("deselected.rs.jquery.bootgrid", function (e, rows) {
                var rowIds = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
                    rowIds.push(rows[i].id);

                }
                alert("Deselect: " + rowIds.join(","));
            });


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Almost sounds like you have another call to .bootgrid() somewhere after your initial call that is resetting the elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  Apparently if you have ajax = true it requires the url parameter.  Once I removed that and readjusted some things I have it working.